# Run a php file in a cron job using whm cpanel

Tags: php, cpanel

**[SOLVED]:** There were two mistakes i found when i checked this directory.

```
/home/usernsme/mail/new
```

Some files were generated every given specific time i.e. one minute in the cron jobs command line.I solved those mistakes by reading these files.

1st mistake was my php binary path. `X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>`path is `/usr/bin/php`

2nd mistake was in my php script.There was a warning:

```
<b>Warning</b>:  session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent in <b>/home/username/public_html/cron.php</b> on line <b>2</b><br />
```

After correcting the path and removing the warning my problem was solved. Thank you all for your help :)

**PROBLEM:**
I am trying to run a PHP script using a cron job within WHM CPanel. Here is my cron command:

```
/usr/local/bin/php -f /home/username/public_html/admin/cron.php
```

My cron.php file is ok. But this command is not executing or running my phpscript after the given time.

Is there anything wrong in my command? If there is, which will be the correct one?

**EDIT 1:** I am running it in every minutes. It does Nnot sending any email. But there is a file generated in every minute in my /home/username/mail/new directory. I also tried by creating a cronn.php file in public_html directory and using this command:

> `/usr/bin/php -f /home/username/public_html/cronn.php`

This is my 1st time of using cron jobs.So i am facing some trouble and can't understand these things properly. Anyone, please help.

Comment: You should consult with your hosting provider about php path at you server. You can try variant without full path to PHP `php -f /home/username/public_html/admin/cron.php`

Comment: Still not working if i only use `php -f /home/username/public_html/admin/cron.php`

Comment: you have ssh access? If have you can check that command in terminal first on you server.

Comment: Please post the output of `crontab -l username`, where username is the cpanel username where that cron is supposed to run

Comment: By default job result is sent to owner by mail. If you do not want such emails you can redirect output to null device by ending the command with: `>/dev/null 2>&1`. So far, that means that cron is running but is failing, take a look into php log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing you want to run your cronjob every 15 minutes, your cron job syntax should be something like this:

```
*/15 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php -f /home/username/public_html/admin/cron.php
```

That means the cron will run every 15 minutes.

Comment: Yes, i am running it in every minutes .But it is not working.

Comment: Well you should get an email about that cron every minute then. Do you get anything?

Comment: No. I don't understand why i am not getting this. This is 1st time i am using cron.

Comment: But in every minute there is a file generated in my mail folder.

Comment: Can you post the content of such a file?

Comment: Solved it. I edited my problem and gave my solution there. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Np. What was the issue in the end?